# email ids related to shared google drive file

Tags: google-drive-api

I want to know the email ids of the users who have access to a file.
I tried using https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/permissions/list . But the output won't contain email ids but Google Account Id and Google Account Name only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Drive documentation shows that the value attribute is not returned on list or get requests:

https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/permissions#resource

if you need the emails, for now you'll need to make calls to the old [Docs List API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/documents-list/#retrieving_the_acl_for_a_document_file_or_collection)

Comment: But the API is officially deprecated.

Comment: Yes it is, however it's still operational for the next few years and it's the only workaround to get the email address.

Comment: Also worth mentioning that Google are looking to fix this in the Drive API at high priority.

Comment: @AliAfshar, you mean the email ids are available through 'googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/fileId/permissions' in future?

Comment: That is one possible solution, but it is a bit more complex than that. I'm afraid I can't discuss more at this stage. Sorry!

Comment: @AliAfshar, any update since January? We are currently developing a new application that uses Google Drive and we need to be able to go from a permissionId to a user's email and we'd rather not use the deprecated Docs API.

Comment: Still working on it, I am afraid. Privacy-related things take extra long time, really sorry about that. If you want to, drop by the Google Drive SDK community and discuss your use-case with our Developer Advocates, there may be slight tweaks you can make to not require it.

Comment: Thanks for the update. We will post on the community. For anyone who stumbles on this thread and wants a direct link to the Google Drive G+ community: https://plus.google.com/communities/107264319205603895037